# How do I prevent a "'boneyard' not found" error when I 'brew update'?

Tags: homebrew

When I

```
brew update
```

I get

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-boneyard/' not found
Error: Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-boneyard failed!
```

How do I fix this?

---

Details:

```
$brew update -v
Checking if we need to fetch /usr/local/Homebrew...
Checking if we need to fetch /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-boneyard...
Checking if we need to fetch /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask...
Checking if we need to fetch /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core...
Checking if we need to fetch /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-dupes...
Checking if we need to fetch /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-python...
Checking if we need to fetch /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-versions...
Checking if we need to fetch /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/wix/homebrew-brew...
Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-boneyard...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-boneyard/' not found
Error: Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-boneyard failed!
Updating /usr/local/Homebrew...
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
Switched to and reset branch 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
Switched to and reset branch 'stable'
Current branch stable is up to date.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "untap" to remove that deprecated source:

```bsh
brew untap homebrew/boneyard
```

But I don't know whether there is any alternative source to `homebrew/boneyard`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, and found that the `brew untap` solution from Darius M. worked.

The error message about github is misleading and should be ignored (hopefully the developers will remove it). This is all about deprecated sources:

```
% brew update
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
Error: Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-dupes failed!
Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-x11 failed!
To restore the stashed changes to /usr/local/Homebrew run:
  'cd /usr/local/Homebrew && git stash pop'
...
```

Solution: for each failed source, run `brew untap` like so:

```
% brew untap homebrew/homebrew-dupes
Untapping homebrew/dupes...
Untapped (335 files, 437.1KB).
% brew untap homebrew/homebrew-x11
Untapping homebrew/x11...
Untapped (309 files, 288.4KB).
```

No errors any more:

```
% brew update                       
Already up-to-date.
```